# HTTPWebRequest not sending certificate

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpcontext

I am creating an POC where it needs to send the certificate from client side via HTTPWebRequest and validate it on server's aspx page.

Here's the client side code where i create the request and attached the certificate

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
byte[] postDataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

request.ClientCertificates.Add(store.Certificates[2]);

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

This is the code in the Aspx File. return is always null or false.

```
public void CheckCertificate (HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I am expecting to received the certificate file in the aspx page and do some authorization logic

Comment: Anyone has the same issue?

Comment: Anyone has the same issue?